# $3 \times 3$ Matrices Equation Problem

Tags: matrices

How am I suppose to convert the following equation into $3 \times 3$ matrices?

$z=2x+3y$

I'm having problem with this equation because only one equation is given. The question before had two equations so, it was easily solved by either using eliminating method or any other method. Please give me some idea to solve this one.

Comment: This question makes no sense: how do you expect to change a linear equation into a matrix? Do you mean the equation's coefficients' matrix or what?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing it could be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\2&3&-1\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},
$$
but it is impossible to tell without more information about what you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're looking to solve for x,y,z?

You only have one equation so you will not have a unique solution. (Also in your previous exercise that you mentioned, if you were given only two equations with three unknowns you should also have ended up with infinite solutions).

$z = 2x + 3y \iff 0 = 2x + 3y - z$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2&3&-1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which, if you prefer, can be written as the augmented matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2 &3& -1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]$$

Since $0z= 0$ is true for any value of $z$, set $z$ as a parameter. If it helps, call this parameter $t$. Similarly, we can let $y=s$ (another parameter).
Then going straight to substitution your solution is:
$$\begin{align*}
z &= t\\
y &= s\\
2x = -3s + t \iff x &= \frac{-3}{2}s + \frac{1}{2}t\\
\end{align*}$$

So if you wanted to find a particular solution for some reason, then you could pick any value for $t, s\in \Bbb R$ (assuming your matrix is over $\Bbb R$) and the chosen parameters would generate a solution set for the original equation from the question.

For Example: Let $t = 2, s = 3$. Then:

$\begin{align}z &= t = 2\\
y &= s = 3\\
x &= \frac{-3}{2}s + \frac{1}{2}t = -\frac{9}{2}+ 1\end{align}$

Plug this back into the equation from the question and you get:

$\begin{align}z &= 2x+3y\\
2 &= 2\left(-\frac{9}{2}+ 1\right) + 3(3)\\
&=-9 + 2 +9\\
&= 2\end{align}$

So you'll find that the solution satisfies your given equation for any $s,t\in\Bbb R$.
This could have also been easily done without converting to a matrix system once you get more comfortable with solving systems.